# How to synchronize python lists?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have different threads and after processing they put data in a common list. Is there anything built in python for a list or a numpy array to be accessed by only a single thread. Secondly, if it is not what is an elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Thread synchronisation mechanisms in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm), reading a single item from a list and modifying a list in place are guaranteed to be atomic. If this is right (although it seems to be partially contradicted by the very existence of the Queue module), then if your code is all of the form:

```
try:
   val = mylist.pop()
except IndexError:
   # wait for a while or exit
else:
   # process val
```

And everything put into `mylist` is done by `.append()`, then your code is already threadsafe. If you don't trust that one document on that score, use a [queue.queue](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/queue.html), which does all synchronisation for you, and has a better API than `list` for concurrent programs - particularly, it gives you the option of blocking indefinitely, or for a timeout, waiting for `.pop()` to work if you don't have anything else the thread could be getting on with in the mean time.

For numpy arrays, and in general any case where you need more than a producer/consumer queue, use a `Lock` or `RLock` from [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) - these implement the context manager protocol, so using them is quite simple:

```
with mylock:
    # Process as necessarry
```

And python will guarantee that the lock gets released once you fall off the end of the `with` block - including in tricky cases like if something you do raises an exception.

Finally, consider whether [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html) is a better fit for your application than `threading` - threads in Python aren't guaranteed to actually run concurrently, and in CPython only can if the drop to C-level code. `multiprocessing` gets around that issue, but may have some extra overhead - if you haven't already, you should read the docs to determine which one suits your needs better.

Comment: is a  `mylist.pop(0)` also atmoic?

Comment: Thanks for the `with mylock:` reminder. Imho RLocks used that way are often the clearest idiom in to protect critical sections in object-oriented programming.

Comment: @willsteel for a definitive answer, I would recommend looking at the Python source code for how lists are implemented, but I would *imagine* that `mylist.pop(0)` would be atomic if `mylist.pop()` is (which I also can't answer definitively, which is why I also mention other synchronisation methods; it may also change across Python implementations). In particular, all C-level code in CPython *may* be guarded by the GIL (but has the option to release it). `pop` (probably) either releases the GIL or not, regardless of its argument.

Answer (score 4):

[`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) provides `Lock` objects if you need to protect an entire critical section, or the [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module provides a queue that is threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

How about the standard library [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)?